# Javascript - Convert JSON Object Property Value from Array to String

Tags: javascript, json

I have an issue where an API call I'm using is sending objects with one property that contains a single array value (`keys` property in response below). Unfortunately I cannot use this format as I must abide by Nested arrays in order to use the outputted values in a separate application like so `[[value1, value2, value3, value4],[value1, value2, value3, value4]]`. I plan on asking a separate question to tackle the nested array section unless someone thinks it is an easy fix (I believe I should use `.map` to convert the object).

**Here is the format of my objects (from `console.log(searchQueries)`):**

```
[ { keys: [ 'hammer' ],
    clicks: 1369,
    impressions: 3151,
    ctr: 0.4344652491272612,
    position: 1.004443033957474 },
  { keys: [ 'woodmaking' ],
    clicks: 207,
    impressions: 6324,
    ctr: 0.03273244781783681,
    position: 4.35831752055661 },
  { keys: [ 'house trends' ],
    clicks: 1,
    impressions: 3,
    ctr: 0.3333333333333333,
    position: 4.666666666666666 },
  { keys: [ 'housing' ],
    clicks: 1,
    impressions: 36,
    ctr: 0.027777777777777776,
    position: 6.472222222222222 } ]
byProperty
```

**Above response is passed from the following for-in loop the result of this API response array being nested in an object originally:**

```
for (var prop in res){
              searchQueries = res[prop];

              console.log(searchQueries);
}
```

Would the `JSON.stringify` method or `.toString('keys')` achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.stringify` or `toString`?

Comment: Yes, `JSON.stringify` just took my variable, parsed it for jus the `keys` values and outputted that result. `toString('keys')` came back with an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 answer=Object.values(searchQueries).map(el=>{el.keys=el.keys[0];return Object.values(el)});
console.log(searchQueries);
```

https://jsbin.com/biyazunafu/1/edit?console

Loop over the main array, turn the Objects (el) keys array into a string, than turn the whole object into its values Array. However, Object.values is experimental, so may dont use this on the users side, instead use this code transpiled to ES5 :

```
answer=[];
for(key in searchQueries){
  answer.push(searchQueries[key]);
 }
answer=answer.map(function(el){
  el.keys=el.keys[0];
  var newel=[];
  for(key in el){
    newel.push(el[key]);
  }
 return newel;
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this one liner?

Comment: @Jonasw thank you for the help, but do you mind converting your answer to something that doesn't use experimental methods and ES6?

Comment: @cphil shure. However i recommend you to use babel, as ES6 is quite cool...

Comment: @Jonasw thank you again for your help and I apologize for how long it took to accept the answer. I get the code to work in JS Bin, but I'm running into an error at `el.keys=el.keys[0]` within my code. It is coming back as `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. When I console log `el.keys` I get back `[Function: keys]` and when I console log `el.keys[0]` I get `undefined`. Do you know what `[Function: keys]` means?

Comment: @Jonasw disregard my comment above. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to turn `keys` from an array into a string, you just need to iterate over your array and make the change:

```
searchQueries.forEach(function (obj) { obj.keys = obj.keys[0] })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I apologize, but I had forgotten what loop was being used to output the results. There is a for-in loop with results being passed to `searchQueries` variable. I believe this might be why I receive a `TypeError: searchQueries.forEach is not a function` at `.forEach`. since it is nested within an object. Would you agree?

Comment: @cphill what does console.log(typeof searchQueries); return?

Comment: @Jonasw `object
string`

Comment: @cphill So you need to convert the main Object into an Array too right? ive edited my answer...

Answer (score 0):

- 1st Get the keys values

  ```
  var keys = searchQueries.map(function(e){return e.keys;});
  ```

This will output :

```
[["hammer"], ["woodmaking"], ["house trends"], ["housing"]]
```

- 2nd: Concat the resulting array

  ```
  var values = keys.join(',').split(',');
  ```

The result :

```
 ["hammer", "woodmaking", "house trends", "housing"]
```